# Inheritance: Function that returns self type?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have two classes:

```
class A
{
    public:
    A* Hello()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

class B:public class A
{
    public:
    B* World()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And let's say I have an instance of `B` class like so:

```
B test;
```

If I call `test.World()->Hello()` that would work fine.
But `test.Hello()->World()` would not work since `Hello()` returns `A` type.

How could I make `Hello()` return the type of `B`? I don't want to use a `virtual` function since we have over 20 different classes inheriting `A`.

Comment: 20 different classes inheriting A isn't that many. You'll end up with 20 vtbls, and one vptr per instance (assuming that virtual dispatch is done that way on your compiler). Are you so resource-constrained that this is really a problem?

Comment: Laziness. When adding a method inside class A, you would have to go to all the classes and add the same method.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), the curiously recurring template pattern:

```
template<class Derived>
class A {
public:
    Derived* Hello() {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    }
};

class B : public A<B> {
public:
    B* World() {
        return this;
    }
};

   
int main() {
    B test;
    test.World()->Hello();
    test.Hello()->World();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost perfect! Would you still be able to create an instance of A? I am assuming it would look like so: A<A> test;

Comment: Just be careful because you'll end up with a separate copy of class A for each class that inherits from it. If @Grapes is concerned about space usage, this may be far worse than adding a vtable for A.

Comment: @Grapes I don't think the compiler will allow A<A>. You may want to rename A to A_base or something, and have plain A inherit from A_base.

Comment: @antonm here A is an empty class, so EBCO would imply no overhead here.

Comment: @mfontanini you may be right on both points there. Especially if typename Derived is only used as a pointer type.

Comment: I'll just end up using ABase and have A inherit from it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm working on a system that makes *very* heavy use of CRTP at present and I'd have to say that compared to virtual functions, it's much more difficult to read / maintain. One specific example is that Eclipse CDT can't deal with it at all. True, it can't automatically resolve virtual functions obviously, but it does a better job than with CRTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can have another Hello method in B, even if it isn't virtual:

```
class A
{
    public:
    A* Hello() { return this; }
}

class B:public class A
{
    public:
    B* Hello() { return this; }
    B* World() { return this; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vaughn, I was trying to avoid that since every time you add a new method in class A, you'll need to go through all classes that inherit A and add the same method. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @Grapes: I think mfontanini's answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Will not work because you are not overriding the method and when you have `A` pointer `A::Hello()` will be called

Comment: @Andrew: In his example, test was a B.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to make `Hello()` return a `B*`. `Hello()` is returning an `A*` and all you need to do is cast your `A*` to a `B*` to be able to call `test.Hello()->World()`. For example:

```
B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(test.Hello());
if(b != 0) b->World();
```

Comment: I want to chain my calls like in the example, test->Hello()->World()->FunctionFromA()->FunctionFromB()->FunctionFromA2()->FunctionFromB() so I am not sure this would work well for me.;

Answer (score 0):

**Starting with C++23**, no need of extra templates.

```cpp
class A
{
  public:
    template <typename Self>
    Self* Hello(this Self&& self)
    {
        return self;
    }
}

class B: public class A
{
 // ...
}
```