# CRTP and functions that return an instance of the derived type

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp

I'm trying to create a base class with functions that, when inherited, return instances of the subclass. Abstract version of what I'm currently trying:

**A.h:**

```
#include <string>    

template <typename Derived>
class A {

public:
    A<Derived>();

    Derived Append(wchar_t the_char) const;

protected:
    std::wstring some_string;

} // class A
```

**A.cpp:**

```
#include "A.h"

A<class Derived>::A() {}

Derived A::Append(wchar_t the_char) const
{
    Derived d(some_string);
    d.some_string += the_char;
    return d;
}
```

**B.h:**

```
class B : public A<B>
{
public:
    B();
};
```

**B.cpp:**

```
B::B() : A() {}
```

What I want to be able to do with this is something like the following:

```
B theObj;
theObj = theObj.Append(L'h');
```

However, I'm having trouble finding a way of organizing the code to achieve this. I'm not sure if there's some form of forward declaration that needs to be here or what. Tried a few things but haven't had any luck. Thoughts?

Comment: Possibly you're looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11761568/1726343

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Well, the thing I want to return isn't a pointer or reference to the existing object, but a copy of that object on the stack with a modification applied to it. I'm also working with an existing code base so I'd prefer not to have to go throughout the solution and change the semantics of the way the class is used. I'd just like to have a base class that I can use to share code between subclasses that are similar but not identical.

The problem with the code I posted is that "Derived" is considered to be undefined at the time the code is compiled.

Comment: @ShiggityShiggityShwa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can you apply any of the accepted answer to the code I provided? I simply don't see a way of informing the compiler about the derived type in time for it to process the template correctly. The functions in these examples always return void or a pointer.

Comment: @ShiggityShiggityShwa I just wanted to make you aware that templates need to be implenented in header files.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Doesn't the accepted answer contradict that, though? How would you reorganize the code I provided to achieve what I'm trying to achieve? Any ideas?

Comment: @ShiggityShiggityShwa Note that the accepted answer actually includes the implementation. That's different from keeping it in a separate translation unit.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this syntax?

```
template<class Derived>
Derived A<Derived>::Append(wchar_t the_char) const
{
    Derived d(some_string);
    d.some_string += the_char;
    return d;
}
```

Having it in a cpp file will not do much good. You better add it to the header file or create some other other file you can include (what MS sometimes calls .inl) to make it accessible to its users.